# Shouldn't quantum fluctuations break thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, vacuum, virtual-particles

I learned that particles and antiparticles are constantly popping into existence and out through annihilation.

But I also learned that annihilation gives off energy.

If this is the case, aren't quantum fluctuations constantly adding energy to the universe?

Comment: But the formation of particle antiparticle pair consumes energy right?

Answer (score 3):

This is a popular misapprehension of the mathematics of Feynman diagrams, which have vaccuum loops of particle/antiparticle in higher order corrections, example:

[image]

> [Feynman diagrams](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Feynman-diagrams-of-the-process-e-e--a-diagram-in-the-lowest-order_fig3_255792498) of the process $e^+ e^− → µ^+ µ^−$. (a)-diagram in the lowest order, (b)-vacuum polarization diagram, the loops are due to fermion pairs-electrons, muons, τ-leptons and quarks.

The b diagram is lower probability , because it has 4 vertices. Note that there are incoming four vectors of $e^+$ and $e^-$ and outgoing four vectors of  $μ^+$ , $μ^-$, i.e. energy and momentum are supplied so that the reaction can happen. The loop gets a fourvector from the input, and gives a four vector to the output, energy and momentum conserved throughout.

The hypothesis that such loops can happen out of the vacuum  with "real particles" is not a measurable phenomenon. Measurement means interaction with real four vectors, and there are none such in the vacuum. There always needs to be a "source" to provide the energy for pair creation out of the vacuum, a real four vector.

Answer (score 1):

Lucas Plz,

In quantum field theory the vacuum represents the ground state. It's energy is constant, so no energy is added. The so-called quantum fluctuations appear only when you measure that energy in some way or another, but in this case it's not just the vacuum but also the system that gets measured and the instrument. Those do have a non-zero energy.